# QPlainTextEdit is RightToLeft but displays LeftToRight

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7, right-to-left, qplaintextedit

I made a view with `QPlainTextEdit` and set `setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)`. The output of `self.plaintxt.isRightToLeft()`is 1 but in the plain text view, persian and english text are displayed from left. What is happen in my code?

**Code**:

```
import sys, re

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, \
    QFileDialog, QComboBox, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.title = 'by PyQt5 and python 3.7'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 500

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.btn_browse = QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.btn_browse.move(50, 20)
        self.btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(170, 20)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 40)
        self.textbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight) # It is in right.

        self.page_view = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.page_view.move(20, 100)
        self.page_view.resize(800, 400)
        self.page_view.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft) # It is not in right.

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I updated my question with adding code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QWidget.setLayoutDirection no longer affects the text layout direction (Qt.LeftToRight or Qt.RightToLeft) of QTextEdit, QLineEdit and widgets based on them.

**To programmatically force the text direction , you can change the defaultTextOption of the QTextDocument associated with that widget with a new QTextOption of different textDirection property.**

> **QTextDocument *QPlainTextEdit::document() const**
>
> Returns a pointer to
>   the underlying document.
>
> **void QTextDocument::setDefaultTextOption(const QTextOption &option)**
>
> Sets the default text option to option.

```
self.page_view.document().setDefaultTextOption(QTextOption(Qt.AlignRight))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: thanks, you know - code-only answers are considered low quality.

Comment: thanks for advice, I will be more detailed in the future :) @help-info.de

Comment: Are you sure that the correct approach to display RTL text is to use `Qt.AlightRight`? Alignment doesn't change the layout direction and will still cause BiDi text to be rendered incorrectly. Maybe you should use `Qt.RightToLeft` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#LayoutDirection-enum)?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `QPlainText`, as it uses internally `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` which does not fully support RTL (automatic alignment for example - like you are looking for). You can use `QTextEdit`, or use a different document layout class (like `QTextDocumentLayout`) in your `QPlainText`.

The reason for those `Plain` classes exist, is to be faster by removing features... which you need.